# Boolean Algebra x+y=0 proof

Tags: proof-verification, boolean-algebra

So I am having a problem solving this proof of Boolean algebra. 
I am trying to prove that if x + y = 0 then x = 0

This is what I have tried

```
x + y
x + (y.1)
(x + y).(x + 1)
(x + y).1
(x + y)
```

But as you can see I am just going in circles, can anyone offer any advice?

Comment: What is $+$ in this context?

Comment: @mvw You can think of it as set theory, replacing $+\ \cdot\ 0\ 1$ by $\cup\ \cap\ \varnothing\ \ {\mathbb U}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x+y=0$ then we have
$$\eqalign{x
  &=x+0\cr
  &=x+yy'\cr
  &=(x+y)(x+y')\cr
  &=0(x+y')\cr
  &=0\ .\cr}$$

Comment: This makes sense, thank you so much!